# How do I read Java source code for Graphics2d.draw?

Tags: java

I'm trying to copy Java's own method of drawing arcs with points to do it in a matrix of numbers (1s being drawns pixels, 0s being empty pixels) instead of pixels. So I searched for Graphics2D.draw method source code and I doesn't call any other method. Where is the source code?

```
public abstract void draw(Shape s);

/**
 * Renders an image, applying a transform from image space into user space
 * before drawing.
 * The transformation from user space into device space is done with
 * the current <code>Transform</code> in the <code>Graphics2D</code>.
 * The specified transformation is applied to the image before the
 * transform attribute in the <code>Graphics2D</code> context is applied.
 * The rendering attributes applied include the <code>Clip</code>,
 * <code>Transform</code>, and <code>Composite</code> attributes.
 * Note that no rendering is done if the specified transform is
 * noninvertible.
 * @param img the specified image to be rendered.
 *            This method does nothing if <code>img</code> is null.
 * @param xform the transformation from image space into user space
 * @param obs the {@link ImageObserver}
 * to be notified as more of the <code>Image</code>
 * is converted
 * @return <code>true</code> if the <code>Image</code> is
 * fully loaded and completely rendered, or if it's null;
 * <code>false</code> if the <code>Image</code> is still being loaded.
 * @see #transform
 * @see #setTransform
 * @see #setComposite
 * @see #clip
 * @see #setClip
 */
```

Comment: `Graphics` is an `abstract` class, its implementation is tied to the destination (ie file, screen, printer) all of which can have different physical requirements and ways of working, hence the reason it's abstract. You "could" pull the source, since Java's open sourced now

Comment: You will probably find, though, the implementations are platform specific and use things like OpenGL and DirectX under the hood

Comment: It will undoubtedly use native libraries and thus be compiled code, code very difficult to read and understand

Comment: I see it's going to be difficult. I made another question here more specific to what I want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738309/how-do-i-make-a-function-to-draw-arcs-inside-a-matrix . Thanks guys,