# How do I make a function to draw arcs inside a matrix?

Tags: python, math, geometry

I need to make a function/method that draws arcs inside a matrix. I would use 1s as points that shape the arc and 0s as empty spots. So the function would produce something like this matrix (only I would use 1400x700 matrix in reality):

```
000000000000000
000100000001000
000010000010000
000000111000000
000000000000000
```

I need to pass the following parameters to the function:

`x:` the x coordinate

`y:` the y coordinate

`w:` the width

`h:` the height

`start:` the start angle, in degrees

`extent:` the extent, in degrees

Now, I don't know the math on how to do it. Anyone could help me?

Comment: What do width and height mean?

Comment: Look into the topic of *rasterisation*.  You could do worse than start with *Bresenham's algorithm* for rasterising a straight line.  As it stands your question is far to broad to be a good fit here.

Comment: Do you want *circular arcs* or other shapes ?

Comment: Thanks guys, anyway I found the solution was to search for Bresenhams's Circle Algorithm (which I didn't know it exist) and adapt it to my specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

A circular arc is the boundary of a domain of equation

```
(X - Xc)² + (Y - Yc)² ≤ R².
```

A starting point can be

```
(Xc + R, Yc).
```

Now from a known point, you can perform contour following, i.e. repeatedly find the next 8-neighbor that verifies the inequation.

This gives you a global idea. Handling the start and end point is a little tricky. And optimizations are possible by splitting the work in 8 octants. But this is a longer story.

Comment: A parametric equation involving trig functions might be more natural, especially given OP's input involving angles.

Comment: @JohnColeman: this works very poorly for raster conversion; you can't get a correct point density. Not advisable.

Comment: Interesting. I guess the problem is that the naive rounding of points on the circle to points with integer coordinates doesn't work out nicely. I learned something new. +1

Comment: @JohnColeman: think of the angles formed by successive grid points with either lateral or diagonal moves: they are quite irregular. And so is the distance to the center.